# Java fails with “Could not find the main class”

Tags: java

I want to run a jar file in Linux (CentOS, 32-bit). But the following error occurs. What is the reason?

```
[root@server ~]# java -jar keygen.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/dgt/jl/App : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
Could not find the main class: org.dgt.jl.App. Program will exi
```

My Java version:

```
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.14) (rhel-1.42.1.11.14.el5_10-i386)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

Comment: You need to install Java 7. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0

Answer (score 1):

From the error message `Unsupported major.minor version 51.0`, have you tried to launch the jar with latest edition of java?

(IIRC It should be compiled with Java 1.7, but you run a lower version)